# Android deep linking doesn't launch app

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking

I'm pulling my hair out over this; the instructions seemed so simple, yet they just don't work.

Here's the manifest activity intent code:

```
<activity
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Buhzyellowtoplighttabs"
    android:name="com.blah.package"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.buhz.com" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

So you would think that when I run the app on my phone, go to my browser and go to `www.buhz.com` it *should* give me a option to launch the app, right?

Comment: after you run the project can you copy paste the console text here?

Comment: Logcat or the Gradle Log? and u looking for anything specific , this is a rather large project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, this will only work when you click a link to the site, not when you type the URL in.

On the off-chance you're reading this on the Android device your testing on, [here](http://www.buhz.com) is a link for you

Comment: Good answer, never would of thought of that, but now i have another issue , if i want to allow users to share individual status updates from my app and one of my users sends a link to a piece of content( "www.buhz.com/updates/123 " and the user on the receiving end doesnt have the app how would i redirect them to the play store?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not really sure. I guess you could display a dialog on the website that says something like "Have you tried our Android app? You can download it here" and link to the app store, although it would display for all users, even those that have the app installed. More info about the link formatting for the play store [here](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html)

Comment: I came up with the idea of a redirect on the corresponding web url that just redirects them to the playstore listing if you dont have the app

Comment: @ChuckKelly is your idea implemented?
can you share your idea and how you implemented? 

if possible please provide a solution for this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69393017/deeplinks-are-not-opening-the-apps-in-android-tablets-since-the-browser-is-set-t

Answer (score 1):

Here is the approach that worked for me

The androidmanifest file content is as follows:

```
<activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="www.example.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/roses"
                android:scheme="http" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The command entered in terminal is as follows :

```
./adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "http://www.example.com/roses" com.example.irfan.helloworld
```

Note:
If your operating system is Windows you can remove the first "./" in the above command.

Result:

It opened the "Second Activity" of my app automatically.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

For me:

```
adb shell  am start  -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW  -d "example://gizmos" com.example
```

didn't work. 
Adding category solved it:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d "http://www.example.com/gizmos"
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks.

Comment: It is for develop aims, what about PROD, opening, e.g. from email?